# Move image on screen

Tags: c++, xcode, sdl

I have an image which I want to be moveable. My problem is that the image isn't really moving, it's just dublicated and a new image loads on the new place while the old position still contain the image.

```
void draw_surface(int srcX, int srcY, int dstX, int dstY, int width, int height, SDL_Surface *source, SDL_Surface *destination)
{
    SDL_Rect src; 
    src.x = srcX;
    src.y = srcY;
    src.w = width;
    src.h = height;

    SDL_Rect dst;
    dst.x = dstX;
    dst.y = dstY;
    dst.w = width;
    dst.h = height;

    SDL_BlitSurface(source, &src, destination, &dst);
}
```

in the main function:

```
while (gameRunning)
{
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            gameRunning = false;
        }
        if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_DOWN)
            {
                dstY += 10; //new position
            }
        }

        //apply
        apply_surface(0, 10, background, screen);
        draw_surface(srcX, srcY, dstX, dstY, width, heigth, background, screen);

    }


    //update screen
    SDL_Flip(screen);

}
```

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use a `while` loop to poll for events
2. Moving the drawing outside of the event loop block is a good idea
3. You need to clear your screen before drawing to it or else the old back buffer data will still be on it

```
Uint32 black = SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 0, 0, 0);

while (gameRunning) {
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            gameRunning = false;
        }
        if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_DOWN) {
                dstY += 10; //new position
            }
        }
    }
    // Clear screen
    SDL_FillRect(screen, NULL, black);

    //apply
    apply_surface(0, 10, background, screen);
    draw_surface(srcX, srcY, dstX, dstY, width, heigth, background, screen);

    //update screen
    SDL_Flip(screen);
}
```